# SQL Server Compact Bulk Insert issue

Tags: sql, csv, sql-server-ce, bulkinsert, sql-server-ce-toolbox

I have a table created like this:

[image]

And in my CSV file something like this:

```
34650326,Mr,John,Doe,Some Street Some City Some Country,33445566,77889900,jdoe@yahoo.com,120.33
```

For some reason the SQL bulk import from CSV will not do I though, keeps saying

> Cannot create script, one or more field names on first line are invalid:
>   Wrong column names:

Can anyone see anything wrong with the CSV?

Comment: which DBMS? which import statement?

Comment: It seems your bulk insert is trying to interpret the first row as headers - you need to turn that off, if you don't have any headers.

Comment: it appears from the error message that your db expects to find the column names in the first line of the csv file. Try adding that line iat the beginning of your csv : `GUI_ID,Title,First_Name, Second_Name,Address,Mobile,Landline,Email,Balance`.

Comment: Yup, that was it, the first row was causing the issue. Once I have added the headers it worked just fine. Thanks